# A finitely presented group $G$ is given by a presentation $\langle S,R\rangle$, where $R$ is finite. Show that $S$ is finite.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-presentation

We were asked to prove this theorem in an exercise. This is what I have thus far:

Suppose $S$ were infinite. Denote the set of symbols of $S$ that do not occur in any relation by $S'$. Then the free group $F_{S'}$ is isomorphic to a subgroup of $G$. Because $R$ is finite and $S$ is infinite, $S'$ must be infinite so $F_{S'}$ has infinite rank.

This is where I'm stuck. I initially thought that this would be enough to conclude that $G$ has no finite presentation, but finitely presented groups can have free groups with infinite rank as subgroups, right?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What is your definition of "finitely presented"?  I'm used to "both finitely generated and finitely related".

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more clear:
A group is finitely presented if and only if it has a presentation $<S,R>$ where $S$ and $R$ are finite.

Comment: Then the question is vacuous.  A non-vacuous version of the question would be "A given finitely presented group G has another presentation $\langle S, R \rangle$ with $R$ finite.  Show $S$ is finite."

Comment: @Eric, a finitely presented group can still have a presentation with infinitely many generators. The proposition is saying that if a presentation has finitely many relations, then this cannot be the case.

Comment: @DanielRust:  I stand by my claim.  The phrase "A finitely presented group G is *given* by a presentation $\langle S,R\rangle$" (emphasis mine) renders the question vacuous.

Comment: Pedants like to distinguish between a *finitely presentable* group, which means that is *can be* defined by a finite presentation, and a *finitely presented* group, which means that *is* defined by a finite presentation.

Comment: @DerekHolt thanks I wasn't noticing the subtlety until you phrased it in that way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A finitely presented group must have a presentation with a finite set of generators (be finitely generated) and a finite set of relations (finitely related). You have shown that if $S$ is infinite and $R$ is fintite (for a given $S$ and $R$), then $G$ can not be finitely presented as it would not be finitely generated. It follows that if $G$ is finitely presented, $S$ must be finite.

Comment: I'm not sure I quite understand.

I have proven that $G$ has a subgroup that is not finitely generated. As far as I know, finitely presented groups can have infinitely generated subgroups. Would you mind explaining how you got around this problem?

Comment: Define a homomorphism $f\colon G\to\langle S'\rangle$ by $f(s)=e$ if $s\notin S'$ and $f(s)=s$ if $s\in S'$. This morphism splits and so $G$ is actually isomorphic to $\langle S\setminus S'\mid R\rangle\rtimes\langle S'\rangle$ which can not be finitely generated.

Comment: Ah, I suppose that a finite product is finitely generated iff its factors are finitely generated? I suppose that makes sense.

Comment: I think if $G$ is finitely generated, then $G/N$ is finitely generated because the image of the generators of $G$ form a generating set for $G/N$. The contrapositive of this statement would imply that if $\langle S'\rangle\cong G/\langle S\setminus S'\mid R\rangle$ is infinitely generated (which it is), then $G$ is infinitely generated.

Comment: OK, I understand. Thank you very much!

Comment: I should have amended the above comments, the kernel of the homomorphism $f$ is not $\langle S\setminus S'\mid R\rangle$ (as this is not a normal subgroup), it is just the normaliser of the subgroup $\langle S\setminus S'\rangle$

Answer (score 2):

Just kill the generators $S^{\prime}$.

More formally: Let $G=\langle S; R\rangle$ be finitely presentable and assume that $R$ is finite. Suppose $S$ is infinite. Then kill every generator which appears (or its inverse appears) in any relator from $R$. You are left with an infinitely generated free group, hence your group $G$ cannot be finitely generated, and hence $G$ is not finitely presentable. This is a contradiction, and so $S$ must be finite.

(If you are comfortable with free products: If $S$ is infinite then define $S_1$ as follows. 
$$S_1:=\{g\in S; s\text{ or }s^{-1}\text{ occurs in some relator from }R\}$$
Define $S_2$ to be such that $S=S_1\coprod S_2$. Then $G=\langle S_1, S_2; R\rangle$ is the free product $\langle S_1; R\rangle\ast F(S_2)$. Because $S$ is infinite but $S_1$ is finite, $S_2$ must be infinite, hence $F(S_2)$ is infinitely generated free. What the above paragraph does is kill the generators $S_1$ and you are left with $F(S_2)$.)